# Can't run video in WebView on some devices

Tags: android, video, webview, streaming, device

This is my first question so please be gentle...

Ok, here is the problem. I have to show a video inside a WebView in Android. 
I have tested it on multiple devices and Android versions and it does not work consistently.

- Nexus 10 (4.2.2) - works perfectly;
- Nexus 4 (4.2.2) - works perfectly;
- Galaxy Tab 10.1 (4.0.4) - only sound;
- Nexus S(4.1.2) - works perfectly;
- LG Optimus One (2.3.3) - does absolutely nothing;

I simply can't find the problem, nor a similar problem online...

This is a sample video I have to display:

```
<html>
<div style="display:none">

</div>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

<object id="myExperience2084424914001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="448" />
  <param name="height" value="282" />
  <param name="playerID" value="1628834100001" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABCTwHZPk~,hTXeDm36Z7Rd3QTKipeWv6uC6OAmrw2j" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />

  <param name="@videoPlayer" value="2084424914001" />
</object>

<script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>
</html>
```

And here is a sample of the WebView in Android...

```
try {
                        webviewC = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewRSS);
                        webviewC.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        webviewC.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                        webviewC.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                        webviewC.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                        webviewC.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

                        // show loading progress in the title bar
                        webviewC.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                                activity.setProgress(progress);
                                // The progress meter will automatically disappear
                                // when
                                // we reach 100%
                                if (progress == 100) {
                                    setProgressBarVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        // show message if error
                        webviewC.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, "Desole! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        webviewC.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.somebaseurl.org", aStringContainingHTML, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh, no! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

UPDATE!

The video section I get must be displayed in a WebView (client request) and I get the html section I just posted from an XML flux, so there is no option there either...

Comment: why dont u use flash to play ur video becoz android has variant version of os and device running in the market with different webkit engine , it will be better to run the video in flash ,onward 2.3 flash player work good .. ie

Comment: Well, because this is how I get the video from the client and because flash is no longer supported on Android, neither by Google, nor by Adobe

Comment: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/flash-player-10-1-android.html,,, you can also host  video to youtube and fire an  intent to launch it , following that intent matching apps will come as a list and u can easliy be able to play video

Comment: some possible solution are here u can have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586475/google-reader-esque-optimizing-of-webviews-on-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that browser not support HTML5 tags for display and playing video.

Comment: Ok, but how come it works on some versions of android and not on others? and what is to be done?

Comment: some times your android  webView and default browser not support to show video try to download Mozilla or any other browser and try to run video. and try to give link to open video in particular browser using javascript.and also enable javascript in webView using setJavaScriptEnable(true) method

Comment: Java script is enabled, as you can see from my sample code. And yes, in browsers, there is no problem, just in webView. And the nature of my app requires that i display the data in WebView, so changing that is not an option.

Comment: research and development