# The Best way To Add iframeVideo in Android?

Tags: android

I am new to android platform, and I want create simple

thats play videos from web via iframe

but the result is horrible ... very very bad

even the user can't watch in full screen

and the size of video is very big,, bigger then webView?

so, if any one know a good way to play video.. with iframe in android, please tell me..

i have tested the code on iOS it's works prefect... so the problem is android...

here's my Code

```
String hrmlCode = "<center>" +
                    "<iframe type=\"text/html\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"yes\" width=\"367\" height=\"320\" src=\"http://video.com/WqPOh.php?get=vid394g5\" allowFullScreen></iframe>" +
                    "</center>";

            CWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                     // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                     // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                     act.setProgress(progress * 1000);
                   }
                 });

            CWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            CWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            CWebView.loadData(hrmlCode, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a very famous issue in android. The iframe just doesnt work as expected and it is very buggy. 
I would say you don't include  but simply provide a thumbnail of the video which directly links to your video file

Look into the earlier solution below
    https://github.com/droid28/VimeoVideo
    [Google Reader-esque optimizing of WebViews on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586475/google-reader-esque-optimizing-of-webviews-on-android)

Comment: okay, should I use Google Reader-esque optimizing of WebViews on Android?

Comment: Yea that would suffice your need